# Uitest refresh control swift

Tags: swift, testing, integration-testing, xcode-ui-testing, ui-testing

I am trying to add *uitest* for refresh control but I could not have done it because of I can't get access to refresh control with accessibility identifier (`refreshControl.accessibilityIdentifier = "refreshControlList"`)

```
launchAppWithArgs(json: OrdersResultJSON.ok, xcuiApp: app)

        let table = app.tables["agendaTable"]

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            table.otherElements["sectionHeader0"].press(forDuration: 2, thenDragTo: table.otherElements["sectionHeader2"])
        }

        if !table.otherElements[""].waitForExistence(timeout: 6) {
            print("XXX")
        }
```

Any suggestion to test it?

Answer (score 2):

To perform a pull to refresh, simply get the first cell and drag it down:

```
let firstCell = app.tables["agendaTable"].cells.firstMatch
let start = firstCell.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0))
let finish = firstCell.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 10))
start.press(forDuration: 0, thenDragTo: finish)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

You could grab the UIRefreshControl's title label and put an identifier on it, like this:

```
func setSubviewAccessibility(for tableView: UITableView) {
            guard let titleLabel = tableView.refreshControl?.subviews.first?.subviews.last as? UILabel else {
                return
            }
            titleLabel.isAccessibilityElement = true
            titleLabel.accessibilityIdentifier = "refresh_control_label"
        }
```

Call this method passing the table view that you've set the UIRefreshControl for and you should be good to go.

Then, on the test side:

```
let refreshControl = XCUIApplication().staticTexts["refresh_control_label"]

            guard refreshControl.waitForExistence(timeout: 5) else {
                return XCTFail("Refresh control label not found.")
            }
```

The only problem remaining is you'll probably need the list loading to take a little longer than a second so that your tests don't miss the UIRefreshControl. It's always good to use waitForExistence.

Comment: the problem with this for me is that it does not go to the next line until the refreshControl is hidden again, which makes it fail the test

Comment: Did you use waitForExistence?

Comment: Yep I used I don't think that's the problem because It's just that refresh control is hidden by the time gets to that point. I even tried to put it before my pulling action and will wait 5 seconds before calling the pull down